# Copying odd-value elements from array in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, tdd

I have the following code:

```
int copyOddOnly(int *dest, int *src, int n) {

  int copyList = 0;

  for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    if(src[i]%2!=0) {
        dest[i]=src[i];
        copyList = copyList + 1;
            }
        }

    return copyList; 
}
```

It's meant to take all the elements with odd values from array src and copy them to array dest. n is the number of elements to be copied from src to dest. It passes most of the tests except for these two:

```
 int a[10] = {0};

  ASSERT_EQUALS(3,copyOddOnly(a,descending,5));
  ASSERT_EQUALS( "{5,4,3,2,1}",arrayToString(descending,5));
  ASSERT_EQUALS( "{5,3,1}",arrayToString(a,3));


  ASSERT_EQUALS(5,copyOddOnly(a,mix2,10));
  ASSERT_EQUALS( "{-42,12,-9,56,123,32767,48,12,-43,-43}",arrayToString(mix2,10));
  ASSERT_EQUALS( "{-9,123,32767,-43,-43}",arrayToString(a,5));
```

Instead of copying {5,3,1} from arrayToString(a,3) it's copying {5,0,3}. Instead of copying {-9,123,32767,-43,-43} from arrayToString(a,5) it's copying {5,0,-9,0,123}.

My first instinct when writing it was to just have it return n, but for some reason this had it failing even more tests. I have a feeling I'm not getting at something fundamental and I can't figure out what. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: For real code, [there are easier ways of doing this](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/copy).

Comment: Well, in your test the `a` array has all zeroes. And zero in C is even (0%2==0). So function always return 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While it's copying across only the odd elements, it's leaving alone those elements of `dest` corresponding to even elements of `src`. Whatever value was originally in e.g. `a[1]` will still be there after the copy if `descending[1]` is 4.

You'll need to keep track of how far along `dest` you are in the loop. This will be equivalent to `copyList` in the the function:

```
int copyOddOnly(int *dest, int *src, int n) {
   int j = 0;

   for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
       if (src[i]%2 != 0) {
           dest[j] = src[i];
           j = j + 1;
        }
   }

   return j; 
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the explanation! I'm still learning so I really appreciate it!

Answer (score 2):

Instead of

```
dest[i]=src[i];
```

you probably meant to have

```
dest[copyList]=src[i];
```

Comment: Thank you! It works now! I'm a beginner to all things programming--would you mind explaining to me why it matters to have dest[copyList] instead of dest[i]? I figured it wouldn't matter since I initialized them both to 0, but I guess that's false.

Comment: The best way to figure out things like this is to "unroll" the loop manually for some simple example.  Write out a table showing the values of `i`, `copyList`, `dest`, and `src` for each iteration of the loop.  Basically you will see that `i` is the index into the `src` array and `copyList` is the index into the `dest` array.  In fact it would be clearer if you renamed `i` to be `srcIndex` and `copyList` to be `destIndex`.

Answer (score 1):

First of all take into account that there is standard algorithm `std::copy_if` declared in header `<algorithm>` in C++. Your function could look the following way.

```
#include <algorithm>

//...

int copyOddOnly( int *dest, const int *src, int n ) 
{
    auto last = std::copy_if( src, src + n, dest, 
                              []( int x ) { return x % 2; } );

    return last - dest;
}
```

If you may not use standard algorithms then the function can look like

```
int copyOddOnly( int *dest, const int *src, int n ) 
{
    int k = 0;

    if ( !( n < 0 ) )
    {
        for ( int i = 0; i < n; i++ )
        {
            if ( src[i] % 2 != 0 ) dest[k++] = src[i];
        }
    }

    return k;
}
```